# Problem with While Loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Any suggestion of whats wrong with my WHILE Loop?

```
    <?php
        include('header.php');
        $manage = "current_page_item";
        include('nav.php');
        include('sidebar.php');
    ?>
    <div class="primary">
    <br/>
    <?php
    $userId = $_GET['id'];
    echo "<div class=\"item_list\">";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = " . intval($userId);
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<b>Title: </b>" . $item['item'] . "<br/><b>Email: </b>" . $item['email'] . "<br/>";
        echo "<b>Price: </b>" . $item['price'] . "</b><br/><b>Category: </b>" . $item['category'] . "</b><br/> <b>Extra: </b>" . ($item['extra'] ."</b><br/><b>Date Listed: </b>". $item['date'];
    }
    echo "</div>";
?>
</div>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: For reference, you shouldn't be editing the code in the question to reflect the answers.  People looking at the question later won't see the original code that caused the problem unless they look at the revision history, and it's a pain to look at the revision history and the answers at the same time.

Comment: To other editors: be very, very sure you're not changing any of the actual syntax or meaning of the code when you're attempting to format it more cleanly. As cHao says, this may cause confusion with the answers.

Comment: @cHao i think the changes made were just formatting and not to fix the code itself

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: see the first revision, on which BoltClock...'s answer is based.  Someone's "fixed" the code since then.

Comment: cHao's first comment refers to tim incorporating our answers into his own edit. My comment refers to the possibility of any reformatting potentially changing the meaning of the code.

Comment: @tim: have you figured it out yet? Do let us know of your progress.

Comment: No im still having issues. Should I repost my code of what I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is here. You're using the wrong variable name to fetch rows:

```
while($userid = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

It should be:

```
while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

Additionally, there's a loose closing brace `}` at the very last line just before the closing tag `?>`. I don't know if it was orphaned by an opening block you left out of your question, or it was really there by mistake.

Comment: I think thats right but still didnt work. What about this statment?                                         $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = " . intval($userId);

Comment: What do you mean by 'didnt work'? Does it give you an error? Try `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and tell me if it says anything. Also make sure error reporting is fully on; place `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Ok I turned error reporting on and Im getting                       Notice: Undefined variable: userid in

Comment: @tim: be sure to accept whichever answer was most helpful to you by clicking the tick under the appropriate answer. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Along with what `BoltClock` said and `stoosh`, you also have a syntax error:

```
echo "<b>Price: </b>" . $item['price'] .
     "</b><br/> <b>Category: </b>". $item['category'] . 
     "</b><br/> <b>Extra: </b>". $item['extra'] . 
     "</b><br/><b>Date Listed: </b>". $item['date'];
```

You had two parans where they did not make any sense, and my bet cause a syntax error. You really should have `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL` and `display_errors` set to `on` for development! It makes debugging this stuff a ton easier.

**Update**

To set that up temporary for a script add this to the top (after `<?php` of course)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
```

Comment: @tim: You can set that in php.ini or to set it at runtime use the `error_reporting()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

On the second echo line, you have a few stray parentheses. Sould be:

```
echo "<b>Price: </b>" . $item['price'] . "</b><br/> <b>Category: </b>" . $item['category'] . "</b><br/> <b>Extra: </b>" . $item['extra'] . "</b><br/><b>Date Listed: </b>" . $item['date'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the closing `}` on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've misnamed your variables?

You've passed `$userid` in your while function argument but you're using `$item` in your loop?

You've also got an extra `}` unless you've only posted a snippet of a function.